# Build failed: cyclic build dependencies are not supported

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I've been trying to build a project in MonoDevelop, but it bitches about a project having a cyclic build dependency.

Project1 is the main project.
Project2 is the one which has the cyclic dependency.
Project3, 4 and 5 are other projects.

Project2 references 1, 3 and 4.
Project4 references 3 and 5.

Project2 and 4 have the same names.

Honestly, I don't see the cyclic build dependency there. Disabling the cyclic build dependency project works fine, but I want to compile it using MonoDevelop.

Comment: Does ur main project (1) reference project 2?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was fixed by renaming Project4.

Both had the same name, and MonoDevelop couldn't resolve it.